# Spring framework: Register conversion-service with java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

How can I translate:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" conversion-service="applicationConversionService" />
<bean class="com.pack.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean" id="applicationConversionService" />
```

where `ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean extends FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean`

into java config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="specifyappropriately", includeFilters=@Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=Controller.class))
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
        FormattingConversionService conversionService = new ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean().getObject();
        addFormatters(conversionService);
        return conversionService;
    }

    public Validator getValidator() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey,How Did You Do That? I have same problem.I m not able to figure out.I want to remove that mvc annotation tag, so how can i tell spring,where to look for conversion-service? Can you please brief me little bit more...

Comment: I got the solution.. thnx anyway.